# Phone-Gap device plugin undefined

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have been reading all type of issue with this on the web and most point to the the confix.xml File. I have modified mind a couple ways and still I get the error.

I have checked out lots of Stack Overflow question none seems to be helping.

Note: I'm running this in ripple.(not sure if that the problem or not) Phone-Gap 3.6.3

config file:

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"/> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.3" />
```

Loading Sequences:

```
    $(function () {

            window.isphone = false;
            if(document.URL.indexOf("http://") === -1 
                && document.URL.indexOf("https://") === -1) {
                window.isphone = true;
            }

            if( window.isphone ) {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            } else {
                onDeviceReady();
            }
        });



 function onDeviceReady()
{
     console.log(device.model);
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Usually* this is due to not wrapping your JavaScript code inside of a `.ready` function which *should* do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Your code.
});
```

**Edit**

I've had cases where Ripple did emulate my project properly locally but not on the server, try to emulate it locally.

Comment: Try it and I'll remove the answer if it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: please re-read the question, I think you might have read it before I edited it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that its not working in the Ripple emulator
However it's working in on the phone.

Comment: It might be that it works locally but not on the actual server.